# How to make Javascript "isPrototypeOf" function return true?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was trying this function to see if different objects have arelationship with each other, so I tried:

```
var o={name:'abc'};
var o2=o;
console.log(o.isPrototypeOf(o2));
console.log(o2.isPrototypeOf(o));
```

Well, it prints 2 falses. I felt weird that, "prototype" is a property/function of each function/object, so how does JS judge whether one object is the prototype of another?

I also tried:

```
var Person=function(){
    name='abc',
    age=30
};
var o1=new Person();
var o2=new Person();
console.log(o1.isPrototypeOf(o2));
console.log(o2.isPrototypeOf(o1));
```

Again, it prints 2 falses, while I expect 2 trues.

Comment: Infinity. `a` proto of `b` and `b` proto of `a`, that's not gonna happen.

Comment: You just assign object references to variables. This has nothing to do with prototypes. To create a prototype chain you need to use either `new` or `Object.create`.

Comment: Please re-read the documentation for `isPrototypeOf`. You "make `isPrototypeOf` function return true" by having the one object actually be the prototype of the other.

Comment: `Person.prototype`   is the prototype of `o1` and `o2`. `console.log(Person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o2))`

Comment: Different instances of a constructor are not mutual prototypes

Comment: Insert `Person.prototype = o1;` after the declaration of `o1` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `o` to be a prototype of `o2` the `o2` object needs to be constructed from a constructor whose prototype is `o`. In other words, `o2` needs to properly **inherit** `o`.

It is not enough that a variable is assigned an object or two objects are similar. One object must inherit from another.

So in the classic sense, this must happen:

```
var o = {};
var OConstructor = function () {};
OConstructor.prototype = o;

var o2 = new OConstructor();

o.isPrototypeOf(o2); // true
```

In modern code you can also inherit using `Object.create()`:

```
var o = {};

var o2 = Object.create(o); 

o.isPrototypeOf(o2); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

After `var o2=o`  `o2` points to `o`. So `o` and `o2` points to same object. Is `o` prototype of itself? No. Is `o2` prototype of itself? No again.

In second part `o1` is not a prototype of `o2`.
Try to call

```
console.log(Person.prototype)
```

You will see the prototype object of *instances* of `Person` (it's not the prototype of `Person` function).

Also you can use `obj.__proto__` to see prototype of `obj`. It's hidden property. Better not use it in production.